# perfBroken dependencies in insralling opencv

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am receiving this error again and again. At the end, getting it has already installed. Please suggest how I can fix this. I tried all solutions mentioned on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) but got no solution.

```
vinayak@vinayak-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-highgui-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-highgui-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libraw1394-dev but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libdc1394-22-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vinayak@vinayak-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxinerama-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxi-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxrandr-dev (>= 2:1.2.99) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vinayak@vinayak-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpango1.0-dev : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxrender-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxft-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libfontconfig1-dev (>= 2.10.91) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libharfbuzz-dev (>= 0.9.9) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.12.10) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vinayak@vinayak-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpango-1.0-0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
vinayak@vinayak-PC:~$
```

On performing aptitude install, I received this

```
vinayak@vinayak-PC:~$ sudo aptitude install libopencv-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gtk-2.0{a} libatk1.0-dev{a} libavcodec-dev{a} libavformat-dev{a} 
  libavutil-dev{a} libcairo-script-interpreter2{a} libcairo2-dev{ab} 
  libcv-dev{a} libcvaux-dev{a} libdc1394-22-dev{a} libfontconfig1-dev{ab} 
  libfreetype6-dev{ab} libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev{a} libgtk2.0-dev{a} 
  libharfbuzz-dev{ab} libharfbuzz-gobject0{a} libhighgui-dev{a} 
  libilmbase-dev{a} libjasper-dev{a} libopencv-calib3d-dev{a} 
  libopencv-contrib-dev{a} libopencv-core-dev{a} libopencv-dev 
  libopencv-features2d-dev{a} libopencv-flann-dev{a} libopencv-gpu-dev{a} 
  libopencv-gpu2.4{a} libopencv-highgui-dev{a} libopencv-imgproc-dev{a} 
  libopencv-legacy-dev{a} libopencv-ml-dev{a} libopencv-objdetect-dev{a} 
  libopencv-ocl-dev{a} libopencv-ocl2.4{a} libopencv-photo-dev{a} 
  libopencv-stitching-dev{a} libopencv-stitching2.4{a} 
  libopencv-superres-dev{a} libopencv-superres2.4{a} libopencv-ts-dev{a} 
  libopencv-ts2.4{a} libopencv-video-dev{a} libopencv-videostab-dev{a} 
  libopencv-videostab2.4{a} libopencv2.4-java{a} libopencv2.4-jni{a} 
  libopenexr-dev{a} libpango1.0-dev{ab} libpixman-1-dev{ab} 
  libraw1394-dev{ab} libraw1394-tools{ab} libswscale-dev{a} 
  libxcb-shm0-dev{ab} libxcomposite-dev{a} libxcursor-dev{ab} 
  libxft-dev{ab} libxi-dev{ab} libxinerama-dev{ab} libxrandr-dev{a} 
  libxrender-dev{ab} opencv-data{a} x11proto-composite-dev{a} 
  x11proto-randr-dev{a} x11proto-render-dev{a} x11proto-xinerama-dev{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 65 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 112 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpixman-1-dev : Depends: libpixman-1-0 (= 0.30.2-2ubuntu1.1) but 0.33.6-1 is installed.
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5) but 2.6.3-3 is installed.
 libpango1.0-dev : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is installed.
                   Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is installed.
                   Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is installed.
                   Depends: libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.38.1-1 is installed.
 libraw1394-dev : Depends: libraw1394-11 (= 2.1.0-1ubuntu1) but 2.1.1-2 is installed.
 libxcb-shm0-dev : Depends: libxcb-shm0 (= 1.10-2ubuntu1) but 1.11.1-1 is installed.
 libxi-dev : Depends: libxi6 (= 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1) but 2:1.7.6-1 is installed.
 libraw1394-tools : Depends: libraw1394-11 (= 2.1.0-1ubuntu1) but 2.1.1-2 is installed.
 libcairo2-dev : Depends: libcairo2 (= 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1.1) but 1.14.6-1 is installed.
                 Depends: libcairo-gobject2 (= 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1.1) but 1.14.6-1 is installed.
 libxft-dev : Depends: libxft2 (= 2.3.1-2) but 2.3.2-1 is installed.
 libxrender-dev : Depends: libxrender1 (= 1:0.9.8-1build0.14.04.1) but 1:0.9.9-2 is installed.
 libxinerama-dev : Depends: libxinerama1 (= 2:1.1.3-1) but 2:1.1.3-1+b1 is installed.
 libharfbuzz-dev : Depends: libharfbuzz0b (= 0.9.27-1ubuntu1) but 1.0.1-1+b1 is installed.
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1 (= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) but 2.11.0-6.3 is installed.
 libxcursor-dev : Depends: libxcursor1 (= 1:1.1.14-1) but 1:1.1.14-1+b1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      libcairo2-dev [Not Installed]                      
2)      libcv-dev [Not Installed]                          
3)      libcvaux-dev [Not Installed]                       
4)      libdc1394-22-dev [Not Installed]                   
5)      libfontconfig1-dev [Not Installed]                 
6)      libfreetype6-dev [Not Installed]                   
7)      libgtk2.0-dev [Not Installed]                      
8)      libharfbuzz-dev [Not Installed]                    
9)      libhighgui-dev [Not Installed]                     
10)     libopencv-contrib-dev [Not Installed]              
11)     libopencv-dev [Not Installed]                      
12)     libopencv-highgui-dev [Not Installed]              
13)     libopencv-legacy-dev [Not Installed]               
14)     libopencv-objdetect-dev [Not Installed]            
15)     libopencv-ocl-dev [Not Installed]                  
16)     libopencv-superres-dev [Not Installed]             
17)     libopencv-videostab-dev [Not Installed]            
18)     libpango1.0-dev [Not Installed]                    
19)     libpixman-1-dev [Not Installed]                    
20)     libraw1394-dev [Not Installed]                     
21)     libraw1394-tools [Not Installed]                   
22)     libxcb-shm0-dev [Not Installed]                    
23)     libxcursor-dev [Not Installed]                     
24)     libxft-dev [Not Installed]                         
25)     libxi-dev [Not Installed]                          
26)     libxinerama-dev [Not Installed]                    
27)     libxrandr-dev [Not Installed]                      
28)     libxrender-dev [Not Installed]                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Edit:

I have tried **apt-get -f install**. It does not work as well.

On lsb_release -a, it gives

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: Can you please include the output of `apt-cache policy libpango-1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev` for more info about the version discrepancy (as seen in the output of `apt-get install libpango1.0-dev`).

Comment: Thank you @DavidFoerster for your help. I want to mention that I installed it from source and there were no conflicts in doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install from source without any conflicts as suggested by a friend. Thank you everyone for taking the time to help me

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.) Ping me if you want an up-vote after the improvement. :-)